# Tool for querying log files with SQL like queries?

Tags: logging

Some time back (Windows 98 days) I recall using a tool that would allow me to load log files and query them with SQL like queries.

I'm looking for a basic tool I can launch in Windows and perform similar queries.  I'm not looking for something like [SEQ](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/getting-started) that plugs into apps through libraries (but has nice looking features and functionalities) or others that require Docker or IIS-only log analysis tools.

I need to be able to load generic logs and perform queries.

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when I was looking for the name of a tech stack I worked with: Elasticsearch/Kibana.

Even though this question is 5 months old, for reference I'll provide this answer for people in a similar search quest.